# Pulseaudio loopback changing source when new source is connected

Tags: xubuntu, pulseaudio

I have an audio stream coming in from line-in that I prefer to have monitored at all times. I use the following command to do this:

```
pacmd load-module module-loopback latency_msec=1 source='alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo'
```

and every time I connect any additional audio source (webcam, usb mic, etc) it changes to that source... resulting in near ear-bleed levels of feedback causing me to either rip the source out as quickly as possible or unload the module and execute the command again.

*I'm naming the source in this command...* why does it keep *changing* when new sources are connected? How do I permanently add a loopback of a specified device THAT WONT CHANGE?

Tried commenting out "load-module module-switch-on-connect" in /etc/pulse/default.pa and had no effect. Thought that would have done it cuz thats a solution I think I've seen elsewhere. I feel like I'm missing something...

System details: Asus Prime Z370-A motherboard, i7-8700K, Xubuntu 18.04, 4.15.0-20-generic

Comment: Pulseaudio documentation for this module shows an additional command option `source_dont_move` with default value being false. try adding `source_dont_move=1`

Comment: What do you know, that did it! Thanks! RTFM I guess...

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of having an actual *answer* rather than a comment: pass `source_dont_move=1` when loading the module ([documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#module-loopback)).